# How to expand dots from model.frame with a character string in R

Tags: r, model, linear-regression

Given data and a variable name:

```
seed = 1253
dat = data.frame(x = c(1:4, NA), y = rnorm(5), extra = rnorm(5))
var = "extra"
```

I would like to create a `model.frame` with all three variables, when only two are specified in `formula`. This could be done with expanding dots as:

```
model.frame(y ~ x, dat, var = extra)
#            y x      (var)
# 1  1.0447865 1  1.4039139
# 2  1.8088280 2 -0.1656416
# 3  0.9614491 3 -0.8215288
# 4 -1.6359538 4  1.0751587
```

However, I need to be able to add columns to a `model.frame` from a character string. My attempt:

```
model.frame(y ~ x, dat, var = var)
```

returns an error message:

> Error in model.frame.default(y ~ x, dat, var = var) : 
>     variable lengths differ (found for '(var)')

How to add additional variables to a `model.frame` from a character string vector of column names? Alternatively, is it possible to expand `model.response` and `model.matrix` with variables that are not present in `formula`?

Comment: Like: `model.frame(y ~ x, dat, var = eval(parse(text = var)))`?

Comment: @r.user.05apr Lovely. Thank you! Would you change your comment to an answer, so that you could get credit for the solution?

Comment: As it is in the same environment, you can use `get` as well `model.frame(y ~ x, dat, var = get(var))`